# How to integrate this integral $\int _{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x^2-1)}}$??

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I want to integrate this integral $\int _{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x^2-1)}}$.

I found that

\begin{align*}
\int _{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x^2-1)}}&=-i\int _{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)}}\\
&=-\frac{i}{2}\int _{0}^{1} (1-u)^{-1/2}u^{-3/4}du
\end{align*}

I'm getting stuck... I don't know how to integrate this function..

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: Where does this come from? The anti-derivative is non-elementary

Comment: $x^2 - 1 \le 0$, and your integrand is not a real number.

Comment: Thus, I change $x^2-1 = (-1) (1-x^2)=e^{i\pi}(1-x^2)$.

Comment: I would guess that for the second part with the $u$-sub, you could use the Beta function to approximate (use $B(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{2}$)).

Comment: In Complex Analysis Stein & Shakarchi, this problem comes from Chapter 8, Exercise 20.. Actually, I expect the integral value $\frac{1}{2} \int _{0}^{1} (1-u)^{-1/2}u^{-3/4} du = \frac{\Gamma^2(1/4)}{2\sqrt{2}\pi}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int (1-u)^{-1/2}u^{-3/4}\,du=B_u\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ where appears  the incomplete beta function.

Using the relations between beta and gamma functions,
$$\int _{0}^{1} (1-u)^{-1/2}u^{-3/4}\,du=\sqrt{\pi }\,\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}$$